# Other player for Youtube on old device

Tags: video, android, youtube

I have an old tablet that I'd like to use just to watch Youtube videos.
It's a Philco PH9B, Android version 4.2.2.

I've found no Youtube app on PlayStore and the reason is because such device won't suitable for the last Youtube version.
But I've found an old version APK of Youtube, suitable for Android 4.2, from apkmirror.com.
After install it, Youtube warns that there is a newer version available (I know that). And gives me just one button: "Update".
Clicking it, I go to PlayStore and it says that my device is not suitable for that new version.

Blind alley.
Deadlock.
Stalemate.

I can watch videos using the browser. But it's very poor of resources and stucks a lot.
It hasn't even an option to speed up the video, at least.

So, I'd like to know if there is another player as an APK to watch Youtube videos on the fly. Not offline videos.
Or other solution to this stalemate.

Comment: What is the tablet model? It sounds very old and the video playback in browser may be more due to a general lack of resources. An app may not be any better.

Comment: Model is PH9B, from Philco. I need, at least, to speed up the video. Once it's playing, I got no stuck.

Comment: Have you explored rooting and unlocking the device so you can install an alternative ROM that might be more up to date, capable of running current apps?

Comment: @music2myear, I'd love to know how to root and update it to Android 5+. Would you say a good tutorial to do that? Is it possible to update Android without have to root the device?

Comment: Without rooting and unlocking the device, your only option for updates is from the manufacturer. The purpose of rooting and unlocking in this case is to open the ability to install an alternative version of Android that is still supported, or supported longer than the version you're currently at. Note that in some cases newer versions assume higher base system resources and so may not be the improvement you're looking for, but on the other hand, some versions are designed for less capable and older devices.

Comment: I do not have specific recommendations except to suggest going to XDA Developers and searching their forums for your device.

Answer (score 1):

Vanced is great, I've been using NewPipe for a bit and it's solid, clean and simple.

Here's a link to check out: https://www.xda-developers.com/best-youtube-vanced-alternatives/

Comment: I tried NewPipe, SkyTube and LibreTube. I had to install legacy versions, but some didn't work, unfortunately... Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Dang. Sorry to hear that. Figured legacy versions would cut it. 4.2 does go back quite a ways.

Comment: is it possible to update Android without have to root the device?

Comment: Once the manufacturer stops supporting the device you'll need to root it to update. I did a very cursory search for roms on xda and didn't find much support for your device. Look into it further to be sure there isn't support out there for that model. 
It could also be time to see what you can pick up for 40-50 dollars on ebay.

Answer (score 1):

For super low resources, as this tablet has 1GB RAM and a 1.2Ghz CPU, I would suggest NewPipe or a less resource intensive browser that has built-in adblock function, such as Brave.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @music2myear,  I'll try Brave. Thanks for suggestion. I'm using Kiwi Browser.

Comment: Kiwi isn't a bad choice. But some may find Brave is less resource intensive, especially as it has decent adblock built in.